# "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch" on node.js deploy with Docker in Heroku

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app to Heroku which was dockernized.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4.2.2

WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN git clone https://github.com/***.git

WORKDIR /usr/src/application

RUN ./install.sh

EXPOSE 80 3000
CMD bash -C '/usr/src/application/start.sh'
```

Also, I have a Profile with just one line as follow:

```
web: node bin/www
```

Following the steps on the documentation, I've pushed the image via two commands:
`heroku container:push web --app immense-falls-39679` and released with
 `heroku container:release web --app immense-falls-39679`.

In the logs, everything seems to be going ok, with the app deployed successfully. But when it is about to start (with the `start.sh` script) it crashes with the error

```
2018-10-23T20:47:44.025502+00:00 app[web.1]: [20:47:44] Finished 'build-app' after 7.11 s
2018-10-23T20:47:44.025958+00:00 app[web.1]: [20:47:44] Starting 'bundle-release'...
2018-10-23T20:48:07.932228+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-10-23T20:48:07.932327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-10-23T20:48:08.058850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-10-23T20:48:08.097770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've researched and most have said that this is due to fixed setting the PORT value. But, in my `bin/www` (where is my server configs), I've already set the port to be either a fixed value or from the process.env

```
var app = require('../out/app');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  listenForNotificationRequests();
});
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

I dont have any other clues on how fixing it. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: if heroku is expecting you to bind to port 80 and you're not, it won't work. You default port is 3000, and $PORT is not defined insde your container, so the JS code goes with the default of 3000. Make sure you bind to the right port.

Comment: Hi @MrE. Thanks for replying. I was actually able to solve the problem. The time to my application deploy was indeed exceeding 60s, resulting in the error. But now I'm getting an issue in the brower when I try to load the pages saying  `Blocked loading mixed active content “http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700”`

Answer (score 2):

To deploy a docker container to Heroku you'll need to adjust your Dockerfile to work with Heroku.

1. Remove `EXPOSE 80 3000`, because it is not used by Heroku
2. When you deploy, the app must listen on $PORT set by Heroku. Your app can access this port with `process.env.PORT`. If you'd rather pass the port in the Dockerfile cmd then you can use `CMD start_app_command -p $PORT`

run `heroku logs --tail` after deploying and you will see that $PORT is replaced with the port set by Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime